# ColSideColors key for heatmap.2 function R

Tags: r, gplots

I have gone through the documentation of the `heatmap.2()` function in the `gplots` package in R looking for a way to code a color key for the `ColSideColors` argument. Is this supported? I would like to show which levels are represented by each color on the output plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legend` function in R can help use to solving this problem.

The code just looks like this:

```
heatmap.2(mydata,ColSideColors=mycolors)
# ploting a heatmap
legend("left", title = "Tissues",legend=c("group1","group2"), 
       fill=c("red","green"), cex=0.8, box.lty=0)
# add a legend in which put your group text in legend, 
# and pass your colors which is used in heatmap.2 to fill.
```

You can get help in this [tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-legends-to-plots-in-r-software-the-easiest-way)